# /etc/shadow & gawk

Tags: awk

I ran this small script on /etc/shadow:

`awk '{ FS = ":" } { print $1, $2 }' /etc/shadow`

It does what it should on all lines except for the root's record I.e. it just prints the entire record. Know why ?

I executed it logged in as root. System's slackware. Kernel 3.2.29. This is quite perplexing right ?

Comment: Well the input is our regular shadow file that ships with every Linux box since epoch. The output is user name & encrypted password separated by single space for allrecords except of root.For root's record, it just prints out the entire line

Comment: I can't copy paste output cuz no internet connection on PC. Using phone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you set `FS` after `awk` read the first input, so it will use the default value of `FS`, which is `a space` for root's record.

You should set `FS` before `awk` read any input. There is many ways to do this:

```
awk -F: '{print $1, $2}' /etc/shadow
```

or:

```
awk '{print $1, $2}' FS=: /etc/shadow
```

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1, $2}' /etc/shadow
```

Comment: Thank you. It just dawned on methat I turn into a bonehead sometimes. You're a genius! I had it correct in my awk file though, I forgot BEGIN in command line. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

```
cat  /etc/shadow | awk 'BEGIN {  FS = ":" } { print $1, $2 }'
```

Or

```
awk 'BEGIN {  FS = ":" } { print $1, $2 }' /etc/shadow
```